# Android receive notification open and cancel event

Tags: android, notifications

I receive data from my webService to generate custom notifications.

I want to track `Intent` to be aware of **open** (click) or **cancel** (swipe) event on a notification , to report server for analytics.

Is there any listener for `onIntentStart` or `onIntentCanceled` ?

Maybe a listener for notifications by `notificationId` ?

**Edit :**

i want to do this without changing user's contentIntent or DeleteIntent or asking user to add lines of code to NotificationHandlerActivity !

Comment: Looking For Better Answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [contentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentIntent) and [deleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) using [setContentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)/[setDeleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29). To find more please visit: [Building a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#click).

In addition you can subclass [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) which is a service that receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

[Here](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example) you can find example how to use it.

Comment: thanks ! , i vote this because your answer were helpful but i think there is another way ! , in parse.com push notification , parseAnalytics.trackInBackground(intent) do this ! , can this help you  to improve your answer ?!

Comment: please take a look at this , https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-tracking/Android

Comment: I think the magic is to add `action` on intent and receive it with `BroadCastReceiver`s !

Comment: @ALU0075 - I have never used parse. In my opinion they are doing `setContentIntent` because then they order you to pass `Intent`: `ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());`. **From parse website**: To track push opens, you should always pass the Intent to trackAppOpened. Passing null to trackAppOpened will track only a standard app-opened event, not the push-opened event.

Comment: @Zeim - but this will overwrite  `ContentIntent` and `DeleteIntent` and intent will not do what user wants !

Comment: is it possible to set two `ContentIntent` Or `DeleteIntent`  ?!

Comment: No, it's not possible to set two `Intent`s. However you can put custom values to `Intent` using `intent.put*(...)`.

Comment: if i put some extra on intent , i need to handle it in Activity , maybe tell user "extends your activities from `PushHandlerActivity`" but this is not what parse is doing ! , maybe adding an Action on intent and receive that with BroadCastReceivers is the right way ! , i mean when intent called , just call my `OnOpenBroadCastReceiver` , any idea ?!

Comment: I didn't tell you to extend any `Activity`, just put extras to intent and use them in your `Activity`.